# Ubuntu 16.04 - Unity - No desktop UI

Tags: unity

**Only** the **windows manager loads**.  So, I still have the mouse courser, have the ability to open a terminal, and connect to the internet, etc...

**CCSM** has **no** **checkmark** at the **Unity desktop**.  I tired every method that I found online but still didn't work.  I also tried, reinstalling Ubuntu, but the same problem reappears.

### Here are my specs:

**MOBO**:  ***Asus A88X-Pro*** Bios Version: 0703

---

**CPU**:  AMD ***A10-7850K*** APU, With Radeon R7 Graphics, Quad-Core
Speed: 4100MHz

---

**RAM**: 1333MHzDDR3 20GiB, Corsair 8G 1600MHz + Corsair 8G 1600MHz + ***Micron*** 4G 1333MHz

---

**Graphics card**: NVidia GeForce GTX 750 Ti

---

**Storage Media**: Samsung SSD 850 Pro 128G SATA

Comment: Could you provide some details about your computer make and model, CPU and GPU?

Comment: As I wrote above, installing Ubuntu dual-boot managed to destroy the boot record. I got back to Windows and I am removing the Linux partition, and will not try dual boot again. I will try and get another drive and install Ubuntu on that. If there is no desktop again, then I will have to assume Ubuntu is not compatible with my hardware, and will try another distro.

Answer (score 0):

So what happened was, first of all, it appears `ccsm` does not use a checkmark for the desktop program.  This is IMHO very misleading because there are checkmarks for everything else.

Second, the default Unity behaviour, appears to be, to slide the mouse to left border and then icons and buttons will appear.  It's great except...  if the screen is misaligned, which may happen - just happened for me, not my fault, somehow the graphics adapter driver misbehaves, the adapter supports that resolution, the monitor does too, but, they misalign.  If I change the resolution, the problem goes away.

OK so if there is misalignment at the left edge, now what??  We have chicken and egg - can't slide the pointer to have the icons show.

IMHO this is a poor design for the default behaviour.  The default behaviour should always be, to have the icons show up, and a little distance away from the edges.

Comment: Did you try the left Windows key to have the icons slide out?  They then may be selected with a number key.

Comment: No.  I am a visual person.  I use the mouse pointer and my eyes.  I see the icons, I click on them.  My mind does not remember arrows and shortcuts.

Answer (score 0):

The point of using the Windows key to get to the launcher is to make the Settings "gear" visible, so you can click on it, then select Appearance icon under the "Personal" section, then select the Behavior tab.  Turn off autohide on the launcher, so it will always be visible, and make it bigger so you can see the icons regardless of how far left they are.

You might check the monitor hardware adjustments for screen overscan, and move the screen right, so the left edge is not hidden.  There are programs like xvidtune which allow you to adjust such overscan/sizes in X Windows, but read the warnings, do not adjust things by much, or you risk frying your monitor.  Get the acceptable modelines, and put them into your xorg.conf to make them permanent (use xrandr for that).